# Is there a command line utility to display the WS private bytes?

Tags: windows, memory

In Process Explorer terms it is **WS Private Bytes**, whereas in Task Manager terms it is **Private Working Set**.

I would like a command line utility to display this information given a process name.

**EDIT**

A powershell script will do as well.

Comment: Have you tried `PowerShell`?

Comment: Just added an edit about it. Do you have the actual command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `PowerShell` you may use:

**[EDIT]**

```
function ProcessInfo
{
    param
    ([String]$processName)

    $workingSet = get-counter -counter "\Process($processName)\Working Set - Private" | select -expandproperty countersamples | select cookedvalue
    $privateBytes = get-counter -counter "\Process($processName)\Private Bytes" | select -expandproperty countersamples | select cookedvalue

    get-process $processName | select `
        name, `
        @{Name="Private Working Set"; Expression = {$workingSet.CookedValue}},`
        @{Name="WS Private Bytes"; Expression = {$privateBytes.CookedValue}}
}

ProcessInfo("winrar")
```

**[EDIT2]**

Here's an improved version which takes the process id as a parameter.

```
function GetProcessInfoById
{
    param
    ([int]$processId)

    Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where{$_.idprocess -eq $processId} | select `
    @{Name="Process Id"; Expression = {$_.idprocess}},`
    @{Name="Counter Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},`
    @{Name="Private Working Set"; Expression = {$_.workingSetPrivate / 1kb}}        
}

GetProcessInfoById 380
```

And here's an version which takes the process name as a parameter. This may return multiple values (one for each instance of the process) and you can identify processes by the values by the `Process Id`.

```
function GetProcessInfoByName
{
    param
    ([string]$processName)

    Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where{$_.name -like $processName+"*"} | select `
    @{Name="Process Id"; Expression = {$_.idprocess}},`
    @{Name="Counter Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},`
    @{Name="Private Working Set"; Expression = {$_.workingSetPrivate / 1kb}}
}

GetProcessInfoByName svchost
```

Comment: `WorkingSet` is not what I need. `PrivateMemorySize` sounds like it, but it seems to correspond to the **Commit Size** in Task Manager. Again, not what I want. Actually, I do not see any property on the Process object that returns the **Private Working Set**.

Comment: I've updated the function so it uses internally the `get-counter` cmdlet, which gets performance counter data from local and remote computers.

Comment: PS C:\Users\markk> $x = "cmd.exe"
PS C:\Users\markk> Get-Counter -counter "\Process($x)\Private Bytes"
Get-Counter : The \Process(cmd.exe)\Private Bytes performance counter path  is not valid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -counter "\Process($x)\Private Bytes"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathIsInvalid,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

PS C:\Users\markk>

Comment: I have fixed the functions. Please check it now. For the example that you gave above, the process name should be `cmd`, not 'cmd.exe'.

Comment: now they work for me too, but have you compared your results with Task Manager? You tag `workingSet` as **Private Working Set**, when in fact it is the whole Working Set, not Private. Why do you tag it like this? And `privateBytes`, although they sound right, actually seem to correspond to the **Commit Size**. Please, open the Task Manager and see for yourself.

Comment: I need **Working Set** Private Bytes, not just Private Bytes. Still +1 for the nice scripts.

Comment: I've updated the scripts. Now the scripts only return the **Working Set Private Bytes** (in KB).