# Batch Scripting: Query process memory usage (private working set)

Tags: batch-file, memory, set, private, ram

I tried this one: [Is there a command line utility to display the WS private bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878927/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-display-the-ws-private-bytes)

But it just went on to a different solution (using powershell). I was wondering if you could help me as I can't use powershell - must be a batch script.

I would like to run an executable, wait 2 minutes, query the PWS in kB and log that in. Couldn't find anything on Google either :(

Thanks

Comment: Try with `wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where Name="cmd" get WorkingSetPrivate /value`

Comment: Good one! 
Why didn't you post this as an answer? :)

Comment: There is not information enough in the question to include a clear answer. The command in my comment only shows where to look for the information. But, do you want to obtain the total for all the pws of all the processes, only some, separate information for each process, what needs to be logged, ...? As i only had a clear idea of where to look, i included it just in case it helps and can be used to better define the problem.

Comment: I guess I just failed at describing the problem (you still provided the solution, though!). All I needed was a way to get into that info. 
Using your command, I was able to query the PWS of a process, wait 2 minute and query again - I verified there was no memory leak in an automated way (mission accomplished).

You provided the key bit. The rest is logic that I could implement myself and is a general batch scripting skill - out of scope for this question.

Thanks again :)